# Get data from elasticsearch request -gives multiple documents- from a logstash pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm having a hard time trying to get some additional data from a elastic instance to a logstash pipeline. The elasticsearch filter doesnt give any exception errors, but no data is being populated in the original event field.

Code looks like:

```
input {
   elasticsearch {
        ...data connection details to some elastic_instance_A
   }
}

filter {

   mutate {
      add_field => { "field_i_need_to_fill" => "placeholder_data" }
   }

   elasticsearch {
      tag_on_failure => '_noctlquerythreshold_exception'               
      index => "%{kibana.alert.rule.indices}"
      query => "%{ctlthresholdquery}"
      fields => { 
        "_id" => "field_i_need_to_fill"
      }
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For metadata fields such as document ids you should use [`docinfo_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-docinfo_fields) instead of `fields`.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that, but still not working.

Comment: That's not what you posted in the example. Can you provide more information then? Mapping, query, etc. Your question is barebones and doesn't contain much useful information to either reproduce your issue or diagnose it.